# Putting icons on top of another image at a relative position like markers

Tags: java, android, google-maps-markers

I want to show a large image (like a map) and on top if it put icons at different locations of interest.

I am trying to create something similar to how markers work at Google Maps.

All in all my requirements are to put pressable icons at specific locations that don't change when the user zooms in and out and will allow on click event

Answer (score -1):

You can likely achieve this by the combination of a view, which was your main view(similar to map), and add view widgets as your wish like ImageButton or ImageView for marker, if you want the marker to stay in the same position in the image even though, users zoom it, you have to programmatically handle the position of markers, by handling zoom events.

Comment: how does this pseudo code help OP achieve this ?